# What is the shortcut key for Run to cursor in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

What is the shortcut key for Run to cursor in Eclipse Indigo?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The function that you need in eclipse is called : **Run to Line** and you should call it with : <kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>R</kbd> in the debug perspective .

Comment: Using CDT, when the cursor is on the required line, I press Ctrl+R but nothing happens. Is there a preliminary setting I should set? The "Run to Line" command is bound to the Ctrl+R in the Windows->Preferences->Keys binding list, "When"->"Debugging" at "Category"->"Run/Debug".