# Add "Run to Line" Button in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, debug-symbols

I am using Java Eclipse, and when I want to "run to line" in the debugger, I need to right-click on the line I want to run to, and select "Run to Line". Is it possible to add a "Run to Line" button near the other debug buttons (i.e. near "Step Into" and "Step Over")? In Visual Studio, this button is called "Run to Cursor."

Comment: If you aren't clicking on the line, how would it know which line to run to?

Comment: I would put my blinking cursor on the line I want to run to, and then click the "Run to Line" button. In visual Studio, this is called "Run to Cursor."

Comment: you can try keyboard shortcuts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598538/what-is-the-shortcut-key-for-run-to-cursor-in-eclipse

Comment: @DavidConrad It is the current line of the active editor (a click on a tool bar button does not deactivate/unfocus the active editor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. To show the *Run to Line* button in the main toolbar, do the following:

1. Switch to the ***Debug Perspective***
2. ***Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective...***
3. In the *Tool Bar Visibility* tab check the checkbox ***Debug > Run to Line***

In addition, the *Run to Line* command is also accessible via the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and via *Quick Access* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>).